# not work dehydrate method(react-query) in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I use react-query in Next.js, and get error when use dehydrate method in getStaticProps.

I read this issue https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/1370 and I install Beta version, but dehydrate Method Does not exist
in Beta version :(

```
Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.dehydratedState.queries[0].state.data.config.adapter` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/products".
Reason: `function` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient());

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <MainLayout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </MainLayout>
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

```
import { QueryClient, useQuery, dehydrate } from "react-query";
const fetcher = async () => {
  return await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
};
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery("posts", fetcher);

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only put json serializable data into the QueryCache. By doing:

```
return await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
```

you put the whole `AxiosResponse` into the cache, which contains non-serializable things - in that case, `config.adapter`, which is likely a function.

Usually, you're only interested in the `data` returned from the request, so that would be:

```
const response = await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
return response.data
```

that will strip out everything axios adds additionaly, and will just leave the json response in the cache, which should also be serializable by NextJs.

> and I install Beta version, but dehydrate Method Does not exist in Beta version

Not sure what you mean with that - there have been no changes to hydration imported from `react-query` directly in `v4.0.0-beta.1`. This should still work like before:

```
import { dehydrate } from 'react-query'
```

Only the imports from `react-query/hydration` have been removed, because they are deprecated. See [the migration guide](https://react-query-beta.tanstack.com/guides/migrating-to-react-query-4#separate-hydration-exports-have-been-removed).